# Jquery paging scroll such as facebook status

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm trying to do pagination scrolling the same as  [this tutorial](http://wekeroad.com/2009/11/27/paging-records-sucks--use-jquery-to-scroll-just-in-time) , and while I use

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
```

It is not working, it doen't show any action. So I searched and found one solution :

```
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $("#productlist").height()) {
```

Note : #productlist is the id of my container div.

But when I do this, my page always appends data whenever I scroll my  mouse. What I want is, loading the new contents only when the scroll bar is at the bottom of the page like the facebook or twitter paging loading.

Could any one show me, how could I deal with that problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('#yourcontainerId').bind('scroll', function(){

  if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)  {
    alert('this will alert only when it reaches the end');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, But when I coded that, It doesn't show any action either error.

Comment: yourcontainerId must replace with your id (id of the div you are supposed to scroll)

Comment: Yes, I used `#productlist`, that is the container that keep all my elements that I want to scroll.

Comment: Sorry, do you refer to the div's scroll bar or the window scroll bar?

Comment: There's a scroll bar in my window. And I also want to use scroll on the window like the Facebook updated status. My div doesn't have the scroll bar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12991/discussion-between-socheata-and-ubercooluk)

Comment: I gave it ready. But it still doesn't show any thing different.

Comment: Try changing "#yourcontainerId" to "body" and try

Answer (score 0):

This one works for a table/div  within window

```
elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()

var elem = $('#box');
if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {
  // We're at the bottom.
}
```

More: http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/